# Given any subset of $[1, 2, ..., n]$, can its sum mod $(n) + 1$ be changed to any value between $1$ and $n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

Given any subset of $[1, 2, ..., n]$, can its sum $\bmod n + 1$ be changed to any value between $1$ and $n$ by adding a value from the original set or removing a value from the subset?

For example: given $n = 4$ and the subset $[1, 3, 4]$ from the original set $[1, 2, 3, 4]$, it's possible to change the subset sum, which is $8$, taken $\bmod 4 + 1$, which is $1$, to $4$ by removing $1$ from the subset. Thus, we have $((3 + 4) \bmod 4) + 1 = 4$.

Comment: What is th point of adding $1$ all the time? You just want to know if you can attain any class modulo$~n$, whether or not you add a fixed offset makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

No.
If $a$ is in the subset and $n-a$ is not, then adding $n-a$ to the subset has the same effect as removing $a$. Hence in such a situation, the $n$ possible actions you can take cannot produce $n$ distinct results. Indeed, in the worst case (e.g., picking the subset $\{1,2,\ldots\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor\}$ you can only achieve about 50% of the desired results

Comment: Right. In particular it is easy to check that a simple modification of $\{1,2\}$ will never change the subset sum from $3$ to$~0$ modulo$~4$ (or from $4$ to $1$ if you insist on adding $1$ to the result).